# Inserting a string into another string ... (sprintf)

Tags: c++, string, printf

I'm getting warnings when I compile something like this...

```
std::string something = "bacon";

sprintf("I love %s a lot", something.c_str());
```

Where it says "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char *'.  I tried converting the text to be...

```
const char *
```

instead but I get a different error.  I'm not committed to sprintf if there is a better option.

Comment: What do you mean by "something like"? The code you posted would error out. Tell us what you're _actually_ doing.

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter of `sprintf` be a buffer for the result?

Comment: "Inserting a string into another string" but you didn't provide "another string" into which to insert. Furthermore, you meant `.c_str()` not `.c_str` (which is how I know this isn't your real code).

Comment: I think you need to call `something.c_str()` as a function.

Comment: @PreferenceBean - you're right it's not my real code.  I'm just trying to understand why I'm getting the error.  I am wrong in how I used the function - I was using it as if it was printf.

Comment: Although it can be guessed in this case, it's better if you show your _real_ code so that errors in your submission don't confuse/detract/mask the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Did you check the reference manual first?

Comment: @Galik - I did not.  I was looking into sprintf_s because Visual Studio was complaining that sprintf was deprecated.  For some reason, I was thinking sprintf was like printf.  Sorry about that

Comment: @PreferenceBean - I agree.  Sorry about that.  I should have been a little more thorough.  I would delete if it weren't for all the comments / answers already.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @cpd1 `sprintf` is not deprecated, the conversion form string literal to `char*` is. But for most uses in C++, `sprintf` is obsolete.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - not safe is what I should have said.  I had to add this to preprocessor - _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS so Visual Studio wouldn't complain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> sprintf("I love %s a lot", something.c_str);
> ```

In that code, you should call `something.c_str()` with proper function call `()` syntax.

Note also that the above use of `sprintf()` is wrong, since you didn't provide a valid destination string buffer for the resulting formatted string.

Moreover, for security reasons, you should use the *safer* [**`snprintf()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead of `sprintf()`. In fact, with `snprintf()` you can specify the *size* of the destination buffer, to avoid buffer overruns.

The following compilable code is an example of `snprintf()` usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string something = "bacon";
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "I love %s a lot", something.c_str());

    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

**P.S.**
In general, in C++ you may consider string concatenation using `std::string::operator+`, e.g.:

```
std::string result = "I love " + something + " a lot";
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have to give snprintf a look as well.  Visual Studio did complain about sprintf being not safe to use and to try sprintf_s instead.  I'll have a look at snprintf as well.

Comment: `snprintf()` is **standard**; `sprintf_s()` is _Microsoft-specific_. I think `snprintf()` has been implemented in Visual C++ since VS2015.

Comment: I ended up having to go with snprintf.  For some reason, I cannot use operator+ with the substr method on older versions of GLIBCXX which I don't have any control over.  While it compiles, running the app fails with the message saying I need a newer version of GLIBCXX.  Thanks for giving this alternative

Answer (score 6):

For `sprintf` to work, you need to provide an array of `char` big enough to write the result to as the first argument.

However, you can (and should!) just use the far easier `operator+` for C++ strings:

```
std::string res = "I love " + something + " a lot";
```

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't look like a correct use of sprintf.
First parameter is supposed to be a char * with already a backing memory.
For example:

```
char *str = malloc (BUFSIZ);
sprintf (str, "I love %s a lot", something.c_str);
```

Comment: Also `c_str()` needs to be a function call.

Comment: If your challenge is something from C++ point of view I don't accept the challenge. I just gave hint about correct general usage of sprintf.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did not use sprintf properly to be begin with.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.  Use `new` unless you absolutely need to use `malloc`(normally interfacing with a C api).